# Getting the application roots

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the my application's physical and relative root programatically, but I am having some problems. I was easily able to get the physical path using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")`, but the relative root is proving tricky.

I tried the recommended solution of doing:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

But this just gave me `htpp://localhost`, removing the last `.com/` part.

My only solution was to access the full URL and try to get the domain by breaking down the string, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `Page.ResolveUrl`?

Comment: Afraid not, I am getting the root from a class file.

Comment: If this is on your dev machine, how could there be a com part?

Comment: God I can't believe I missed that... Thanks dude!!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be of help in working out the path syntax:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

You should see the .com part on the live server.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what you want to end up with?

Comment: For example if I access the server variable `SERVER_NAME` I get back `/` and not the full domain like it says on his page.

Answer (score 0):

It is so late that I forgot that there is no `.com` on localhost. I got it to work by doing this `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)`.